# Can you check analyticity of a complex function in Wolfram Mathematica?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

Can you check analyticity of a complex function in Wolfram Mathematica?

Comment: You could try [FunctionAnalytic](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionAnalytic.html) `Tests whether  f(x) is an analytic function for x∈dom.`

Comment: @Nasser Thank you so much

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Searching for "analytic function" in the documentation gives you the answer immediately. Please do a basic documentation search before asking.